# zip(list1, list2) in Jinja2?

Tags: python, code-generation, jinja2

I'm doing code generation in Jinja2 and I frequently want to iterate through two lists together (i.e. variables names and types), is there a simple way to do this or do I need to just pass a pre-zipped list? I was unable to find such a function in the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) or googling.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Modify the jinja2.Environment [global namespace](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#the-global-namespace) itself if you see fit.

```
import jinja2
env = jinja2.Environment()
env.globals.update(zip=zip)
# use env to load template(s)
```

This may be helpful in separating view (template) logic from application logic, but it enables the reverse as well. #[separationofconcerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: For a Flask app:  `app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip)`

Comment: For a Pyramid app, use `env = config.get_jinja2_environment()`. Then continue as above. See https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_jinja2/en/latest/api.html for details about how to use that method properly in your app configuration.

Answer (score 31):

Since you didn't mention if you are using Flask or not I figured I'd add my findings.

To be used by a `render_template()` create the 'zip' filter using the `zip()` function in the Jinja2 environment used by Flask.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
```

To use this within a template do it like this:

```
{% for value1, value2 in iterable1|zip(iterable2) %}
    {{ value1 }} is paired with {{ value2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind that strings are iterable Jinja2 so if you try to zip to strings you'll get some crazy stuff.  To make sure what you want to zip is iterable and not a string do this:

```
{%  if iterable1 is iterable and iterable1 is not string 
   and iterable2 is iterable and iterable2 is not string %}
    {% for value1, value2 in iterable1|zip(iterable2) %}
        {{ value1 }} is paired with {{ value2 }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  {{ iterable1 }} is paired with {{ iterable2 }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Really helpful answer with adding configuration to flask app

Answer (score 9):

For Flask, you can pass the zip in the `render_template()`

```
  return render_template("home.html", zip=zip)
```

Comment: I got the solution from @Chris Farr comment from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644035/how-to-show-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-existing-flask-html-table

Answer (score 4):

I don't think templating languages allow doing zip of two containers over for loop. Here is a similar question for [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-temlates) and jinja templating is very close to django's.

You would have prebuild zipped container and pass to your template.

```
>> for i,j in zip(range(10),range(20,30)):
...     print i,j
...
```

Is equivalent to

```
>>> [(i,j) for i,j in zip(range(10),range(20,30))]
```

Comment: OK, I suspected as much. FWIW, I solved this by putting combining my lists into a single list of a new class, which is probably more elegant anyway.