# How to increment two variables on a for-loop in jinja template?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am developing a web using flask. I have two class objects from models.py. I need to loop over both of them at the same time in my HTML file using Jinja2.

For example:
I want to have the following code in jinja2 format:

```py
for i,j in zip(items, team):
    a= i+j
```

Want to convert it to jinja2 format:

```
{% for i,j  in zip(items, teams) %}
    {% a=i+j %}
{% endfor%}
```

What is the problem with this jinja2 code?

Comment: Please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Jinja doesn't actually have a `zip` [global function](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-global-functions). So you need to make it available by doing:

```py
app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip)
```

Additionally, assignments require using the [`set` keyword](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#assignments), e.g. `{% set a = i + j %}`

```
{% for i, j in items %}
    {% set a = i + j %}

{% endfor %}
```

See also: ["`zip(list1, list2)` in Jinja2?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208252/ziplist1-list2-in-jinja2)

Comment: Thank you , it was very helpful. I just did this and worked:
in __init__.py :
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip


{% for i, j in items | zip(teams) %}
 {% set a = i + j %}
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , it was very helpful. I just did this and worked:
in **init**.py file I add this:

```
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
```

in the index.html:

```
{% for i, j in items | zip(teams) %}
 {% set a = i + j %}
{% endfor %}
```