# Flask: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) from list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to iterate through `GoalHours` and `GoalNames` to get `names` & `hours`.

HTML

```
{% for names, hours in  GoalHours, GoalNames %}
   <input  type="submit" value="{{names}}: {{ hours }}" class="btn" name="remove" required> Hrs 
{% endfor %}
```

Flask

```
@blueprint.route('/goals' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def goals():
    goal_ = theGoal(str(flask.session['id']))
    goalNames_ = goal_['goalName']
    goalHours_ = goal_['goalHours']
    
    return render_template('/accounts/goals.html', calList = calList, GoalHours = goalHours_, GoalNames = goalNames_)
```

I keep on getting:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I tried every web solution from zipping to adding various iter methods to importing [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208252/ziplist1-list2-in-jinja2) which gave `AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'jinja_env'`. Really appreciate your help

Comment: This question is answered in the article above. I have tested passing zip in template variable and use it in Jinja2 as you would in Python works. So just pass zip=zip on your app and zip(A,B) on Jinja2

Comment: Gotcha! Yeah that did the job. I saw that answer in the post too & tried it out but since it only had 1 vote (until I upvoted it too) & it didn't work as I didn't know if I should add `zip(a,b)` as the verified answers didn't show or only showed for one (A or B) i didn't know I had to add for both. Thanks for your comprehensive answer!