# display two python lists in html using jinja template as two columns in web page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have two python lists:

```py
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
```

I have tried:

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table id="data">
    <tr>{% for num in list_1 %}
      <td>{{num}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>{% for alp in list_2 %}
      <td>{{alp}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

With these two lists I want to create a table in a webpage using jinja like below:

[image: wanted table]

I can do it when using a single list. But how to do it with multiple lists?

Comment: [What have you tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please help us to reproduce your problem by e.g. posting your try and describe where exactly your problem is.

Comment: `  <div class="tableFixHead">
    <table id="data">
      <tr>{% for alp in list_1 %}
        <td>{{alp}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one `{% endfor %}` for two iterations. [This looks wrong](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for), also `td` and `tr` elements [looks mixed up](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). What I would recommend is to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists in the backend like this:

```py
data = zip(list_1, list_2)
```

and then iterate over these tuple pairs in the frontend:

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table id="data">
    {% for num, alp in data %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ num }}</td>
      <td>{{ alp }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
```

*(You can use the zip functionality also in the frontend, [e.g. via Jinja2 filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5208252/2648551), of course.)*