# Jinja2 nesting of a dictionary containing two lists

Tags: sqlite, flask, jinja2

Simple question that probably doesn't require a lot of code:

How using jinja2 can I display a dictionary (shown below) consisting of two lists, interspersing the items in the second list with those of the first?

The keys of the dictionary are "titles" and "results".

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{   'titles': [('title-1',), ('title-2',), ('title-3',)], 

    'results': [
        (1, 'author-1', publisher-1', genre-1),
        (2, 'author-2', publisher-2', genre-2), 
        (3, 'author-3', publisher-3', genre-3)
    ]
}
```

Desired output is as follows:

```
title-1

author-1, publisher-1, genre-1

title-2

author-2, publisher-2, genre-2

title-3

author-3, publisher-3, genre-3
```

This is flask-sqlite3 output and I also don't understand the trailing commas in 'titles', which I suppose is an unrelated issue.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

I've been looping (no pun intended) in circles for hours with jijna2 templates trying many different permutations without success, using suggestions from other answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you looked into using [zip in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208252/ziplist1-list2-in-jinja2)? I believe you could do what you are looking for with something similar to, `{% for title, results in data['titles']|zip(data['results']) %}...`

Comment: Thank you Patrick Yoder. With your hint and the reference to another question about "zip" someone inserted at the top I got it to work almost immediately. The code on the other page (zip(list1, list2) in Jinja2? ) was too abstract for me to understand as a novice, so your use of my variables in your example set me straight. I'll post my code when I test it a little more but it looks good. I'll recommend keeping my own as a separate question because the example is a lot more simple to a non-expert.

The other page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208252/ziplist1-list2-in-jinja2

Answer (score 0):

Using the comment given by Patrick Yoder above:

In app.py:

```
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
```

The SQL execution in app.py that creates the 2 lists (titles and results):

```
con = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
cur = con.cursor()
```

Two SQL statements in named strings, then ...

```
query1 = cur.execute(sql_1)
titles = cur.fetchall()

query2 = cur.execute(sql_2)
results = cur.fetchall()
```

To create the dictionary, which is named "data"

```
data = { "titles": titles , "results": results  }

return render_template("/custom-search.html", data=data)
```

tldr; here is the solution ...

On the custom-search.html page (relevant items only)

```
{% if data %}

{% for titles, results in data['titles']|zip(data['results']) %}
```

In two list item tags ...

```
{{ titles }}

{{ results }}

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

I wish I could figure out how to remove the opening and closing parentheses in each line of output, but that's a separate issue.

Update, from Stackoverflow on removing the parentheses: I'm trying to represent a list as a string, so in my code I need to create a string from the list, rather than changing the way the list is displayed in the jinja template. But I think that would screw up my "for" loop, so I'll live with the parentheses.

Comment: By god you're right, I don't even need the counter:
Removed {% set count = namespace(value=0) %}
Removed {{ data.titles[count.value] }}
Removed {{ data.results[count.value] }}
Removed {% set count.value = count.value + 1 %}
Thank you Patrick