Jinja - sort a list by another list
I have this jinja code:
select
{% for field in (["a", "b", "c"])|sort() %}
    {% if field.startswith('mac_') %}
        macro_init[{{field}}],
    {% else %}
        {{field}},
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}  

union all

select
{% for field in (["a", "c", "mac_b"])|sort(attribute=["a", "b", "c"].index ) %}
    {% if field.startswith('mac_') %}
        macro_init[{{field}}],
    {% else %}
        {{field}},
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}  

I am trying to sort the second list (the one with "mac_b") by the values of the first list (["a", "b", "c"]), so the compiled output would look like this:
select
        a,
        b,
        c,
    
union all

select
        a,
        macro_init[mac_b],
        c,
        


You need break down what do you mean sort one list by another, maybe give a better example. Also mention what result you actually getting.

Is there a reason you wan to do this in jinja rather than in the python handler?

The usual solution in Python is to zip to lists together, but apparently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208252/ziplist1-list2-in-jinja2 you need a few tricks in order to use zip within jinja. After you combine two list in one, it is easy. using index is not considered very efficient
