# Using index from iterated list

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

I'm trying to display values from a different list based on the index that is currently being iterated over on another list but cannot figure out how to access the individual items..

```
{% for row in myarray.all %}
    <tr>
    <th>{{ my_other_array_where_I_cant_access_elements.forloop.counter }}</th>
    <td>{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see I have tried to use `forloop.counter` but this doesn't display anything, it just creates an empty table header element.

My other array is defined within the view as the following, and if I remove the `forloop.counter` then I am able to see the entire array printed to the table header

```
 my_other_array_where_I_cant_access_elements = ["X", "Y", "Z", "XX", "YY"]
```

Please let me know if I've missed any required details.

Comment: Shouldn't it be forloop.counter0 (to have a 0-based index) ?

Comment: @manuBriot - I would expect that to at least show some values if that were the case (for the record I also tried that and it still doesnt show any values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to iterate over two lists at the same time, in other words [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) lists.

If this is the case, it is better to do this in the view and pass inside the context:

```
headers = ["X", "Y", "Z", "XX", "YY"]
data = zip(headers, myarray.all())
return render(request, 'template.html', {'data': data})
```

Then, in the template:

```
{% for header, row in data %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
        <td>{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've just taken a look into implementing this and it isn't possible since `myarray` is actually a more deep rooted array inside another object, and I would like to avoid having to store these headers in a database (where the object is stored).. is there a solution like this on the template side or do I just have to bite the bullet and have the headers in the database?

Comment: @Sayse custom template filter could be an option in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14857664/771848.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into implementing that, looks like exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible approach, which I just tried. It only works if you only use the second array as part of a single for loop, though, and does not use the loop index:

```
arr = ["1-0", "1-1"]     # your first array
arr2 = ["2-0", "2-1"]    # your second array

class wrap(object):
    def __init__(self, ref):
        self.ref = ref
        self.idx = -1
    def next(self):
        self.idx += 1
        return self.ref[self.idx]

return render_to_response('...', { "arr": arr, "wrap": wrap(arr2) })
```

And the template is:

```
{% for row in arr %}
<h1>Row {{ row }} at {{ forloop.counter }} matches {{ wrap.matching }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```