# How to parse list of lists in django template?

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

```
{% for repo in repo_info %}

{% for branch in branch_info[forloop.counter] %}
            <li>Branch Name --> {{ branch }}</li>           
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

`branch_info` is a list of lists.

It gives me error that could not parse the remainder on this ---> branch_info[forloop.counter]

Is there any way to parse over the list elements which are also a list?

Comment: Please create an [mcve]. What is `branch_info`? You can't use python inside of a django template

Comment: Related: [Using index from iterated list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25245985/1324033)

Comment: can you share the content in `repo_info` var?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that returns the data at the requested index

```
#  some file named my_template_tags.py
@register.simple_tag
def at_index(data, index):
    return data[index]
```

This will throw an exception if you use an invalid index. If you don't want an exception, you will have to catch it and return some valid data.

It can also be used with dictionaries but you pass in the key instead of the index.

```
{% load my_template_tags %}

{% for repo in repo_info %}

    {% for branch in branch_info|at_index:forloop.counter %}
            <li>Branch Name --> {{ branch }}</li>           
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when your template code start being messy like this it means your data don't have the right structure.  In this case, it seems that you are relying on `repo_info` and `branch_info` being "parallel sequences" (data at `branch_info[x]` are for repo at `repo_info[x]`).

The cleanest solution would be for `repo` to hold it's own list of `branch` so you can just iterate over `repo_info` and then for each repo iterate over `repo.branches`.

If you cannot easily structure your data this way, another solution is to [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (or `itertools.izip`) `repo_info` and `branch_info` together in your view so you can iterate on `(repo, branches)` tuples in your template.