# Looping over two lists in a template

Tags: django

In a Django template, I want to access the elements in one list, whilst looping over elements in another list. So, I pass the lists `mylist1` and `mylist2` (both have the same number of elements) to the template as context variables, and I want to loop through `mylist1`, display the element, and then also display the corresponding element of `mylist2`. It would look something like this:

```
{% for result in mylist1 %}
    <p>result</p>
    <p>{{ mylist2.forloop.counter }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

What's the correct solution?

Comment: Which is the relation between `mylist1` and `mylist2`?

Comment: They have the same number of elements. I realise that I could probably zip them and pass them as the same variable, but I'm wondering if there's a solution to the specific problem above.

Comment: So you just want to display the number of elements of `mylist2`?

Comment: No, I want to display the corresponding element. So, I want to display `mylist1[0]` and `mylist2[0]`, then `mylist1[1]` and `mylist2[1]`, and so on ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates