# Displaying two querysets of model objects one after another in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two querysets of model objects that I want to display one after another in an html page.

The first queryset contains a list of local restaurants and the other a list of chain restaurants. So my lists are defined as such:

```
local_restaurants = LocalRestaurants.objects.all()
chain_restaurants = ChainRestaurants.objects.all()
```

Is there a best practice for listing these restaurants one restaurant after another until the sets are depleted?

For example an html would display the restaurants like this:

```
localRestaurant1
chain_restaurant1
localRestaurant2
chain_restaurant2
localRestaurant3
chain_restaurant3
...
```

**Edit** 
If one of the sets is depleted then the other set should still continue until it is also depleted. So if one list has 3 objects and the other has 7, it should look like this:

```
localRestaurant1
chain_restaurant1
localRestaurant2
chain_restaurant2
localRestaurant3
chain_restaurant3
localRestaurant4
localRestaurant5
localRestaurant6
localRestaurant7
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4238261/1164082

Comment: This is not a duplicate, in this case the lists might be of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools` to combine the querysets, like so:

```
from itertools import chain
result_list = list(chain(local_restaurants , chain_restaurants))
```

If the two querysets share a common field you can also sort the resulting list (Python 2.4 & later for `attrgetter` otherwise use a `lambda` function)

```
from operator import attrgetter
result_list = sorted(
    chain(local_restaurants , chain_restaurants),
    key=attrgetter('date_created'))
```

Then in your template you just iterate over the list:

```
{% for item in result_list %}
     {{ item.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Should give you the result you're after.

Comment: What is the purpose of chaining the results if there is no field to sort them? The @OozeMeister answer is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This function will combine your lists the way you intend:

```
def combine(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) < len(list2):
        list3 = list2[len(list1):]
    else:
        list3 = list1[len(list2):]
    return list(sum(list(zip(list1, list2)), ())) + list3
```

Usage:

```
restaurants = combine(local_restaurants, chain_restaurants)
```

Template:

```
{% for restaurant in restaurants %}
     {{ restaurant.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I will give this a try and report back. I tried the solution that was given by @OozeMeister, but it didn't do what I wanted it to do. The "zip solution" stops whenever one of the lists is depleted. I would like the list that still contains objects to continue until it also runs out of objects.

Comment: I finally had a chance to try this out. This doesn't work. That or I'm iterating through this list wrong.

Comment: Hmm The zip solution was ok because I could manipulate the objects from each list at the same time-- the problem was that it stopped preemptively. I think with your code the fields have to have the same name.