# How do I use two lists in one Django for tag?

Tags: django, tags

I have two letters that I would like to show in my template at the same time. How can I do it in the template the fastest and easiest way?

Where set_1 = A, B, C, D,
ser_2 = result from my django queryset

Is there something like the below? Any help will be appreciated

```
{% for b in set_1 and a in set_2 %}
    <p>{{ b }} - {{ a }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

How can I use this when my queryset returns a list of fields in my form, as in the view below?

views.py

```
def account(request):
    data_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    test = Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_name='Monday')
    #my form
    TimeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Time, fields=('free_or_no',), labels={'free_or_no': '*odznacz jeżeli zajęte',})

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = TimeFormSet(
            request.POST,
            queryset=Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_name='Monday'),
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:account'))
    else:
        formset = TimeFormSet(queryset=Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_name='Monday'))

    list_form = zip(formset, test)


    context = {'data_now': data_now, 'time_edit_form': formset, 'test': test, 'list_form': list_form}
    return render(request, 'account.html', context)
```

If I do everything as in your link, my browser returns an error:

```
IntegrityError at /account/
NOT NULL constraint failed: app_time.time_equivalent
```

**html file**

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ time_edit_form.management_form }}
        {% for item1, item2 in list_form %}
                <p>{{item2}} {{item1}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"> ZapiszXXX</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: [Zip the lists together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates)

Comment: Are set_1 and set_2 the same length?

Comment: yes, they are the same length

Comment: Can I use this if one of the lists is a form field? if so, do you see what's wrong with my situation?