# Django: iterate over 2 sets using for in template

Tags: python, django

I want to iterate over 2 sets of data and display values in my template.

I have something like that:

```
{% for email,phone in user.email_set.all, user.phone_set.all %}
{{email}} {{phone}}

{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately I get TemplateSyntaxError:

```
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y'
```

Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: This looks a bit odd in the first place. What if the `email_set` contains more (or less) elements than the `phone_set`?

Comment: You can create a dict of { email : phone }. The way you did makes no sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yea, but it doesnt matter if this sets arent equals to each other. I just want to display them in one line. I can do second loop and separately display phone and email, but they will be presented in ugly way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through two lists in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates)