# Django Object Filter

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have a simple filter where a user enters a string, `term`, which is compared against the column `companyId` in my local database. If there is a match, the appropriate record/s are then rendered in a table within my template. However, no data is being rendered in the template, only rows of empty fields matching the number of records for a particular query. I have similar logic used for displaying these records unfiltered which works fine.

Edit:

When I removed the key value and tried to render only the object such as `{{ object }}`, the following is displayed: `(Opportunity: Opportunity object (8)`

views.py

```
def opportunity_dashboard(request):
    try:
        term = request.GET.get('search_query')
        if term:
            filtered_objects = Opportunity.objects.filter(companyId__icontains=term)

filtered_local_zip = zip(filtered_objects)

context = {
    'term': term,
    'filtered_local_zip': filtered_local_zip,
    'filtered_connectwise_zip': filtered_connectwise_zip
}

return render(request, 'website/opportunity_dashboard.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{% if term %}
{% for object in filtered_local_zip %}
<tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://solutions.byteworks.com/new_opportunity/new_opportunity_review?id={{ object.id }}">&#9998;</a>
    </th>
        <td>
            <div class="select">
                <select disabled id="bw_status" name="status">
                    <option value="{{ object.status }}">{{ object.status }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a{{ object.opportunityName }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ object.companyId }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="select">
                <select id="bw_account_manager" name="account_manager">
                    <option value="{{ object.accountManager }}">{{ object.accountManager }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Comment: if you are using python3, replace `zip(filtered_objects)` with `list(zip(filtered_objects))`

Comment: @YamanAhlawat I am, but have not had any issues so far without list declaration. I made the change and no data is being rendered still. For instance, `{{ object.accountManager }}`, there is no value where there should be one.

Comment: `for object in context.filtered_local_zip`
You are passing context as a dict. You need to either iterate on dict or change the forloop to iterate on context.filtered_local_zip.

Comment: you don't need to use zip. just do `list(filtered_objects)`

Comment: @YamanAhlawat please see my edit, apparently I am returning some data, but only a description of the database object and not the actual values of the record

Comment: @YamanAhlawat sorry, for the sake of clarity in this problem I have redacted a second database object I am rendering, hence the usage of `zip`.

Comment: What happens if you completely remove zip()? Simply pass filtered_objects and iterate over it.

Comment: @Saturnix thats correct.

Comment: @t0bi if you are getting object, just access the fields `object.some_field`

Comment: @Saturnix I removed `zip` and I was able to iterate over the data, however, I do need to use `zip` as I have more than one object I am rendering and iterating over in congruence. Why would `zip` be giving me issues when iterating? I have the same exact logic used elsewhere except I do not filter the object and it works fine.

Comment: if you are using python 3, zip gives an iterator

Comment: Then this is a different problem from the one your question asks, which is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates

Comment: @Saturnix no, I am able to iterate over two or more lists fine, but when I use a filter on my object, this is when I have issues accessing the key value. So, `{{ object.status }}` does not return a value while it does without the object filter.

Comment: Why do you use {{ object.status }}? The link I've posted shows you have to either change the iterator or use {{ object.0.status }}

Comment: @t0bi updated my answer to include a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `zip()` nor `list()` to iterate over a queryset in a Django template.

Simply pass it to the context.

```
filtered_local_zip = filtered_objects
```

and in the template iterate over it like you're already doing:

```
{% for object in filtered_local_zip %}
```

If you need to iterate over `zip()`, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238261/1307020

Which suggests either this

```
{% for object0, object1 in filtered_local_zip %}
```

or this

```
{{ object.0.property }}
```

Demonstration: https://repl.it/repls/UntidyLimpingCollaborativesoftware

Comment: Please see my reply to your comment, this works, however I am passing four objects to my template for iteration in congruence. Hence the usage of `zip`. If you have any ideas I would very much appreciate them.

Comment: @t0bi pass all queryset separately, create key, value pairs in context. and loop through them individually if you don't want to use zip