# Passing zip object to "include" tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to use `include` to embed one child template into parent template. In the parent template, suppose I need to pass variables as following ( as per the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)):

```
{% include "table/order_item_modals.html" with item_change_form_list=item_change_form_list %}
```

This works if the variable `item_change_form_list` is non-object type (such as string, numeric, of normal list, etc). If I want to pass a `zip` object, the above tag does not work.
The reason I want to pass a `zip` object is because in my child template, I would like to use `for` loop over multiple lists in parallel, similar to a problem in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates).
Here, my variable `item_change_form_list` is defined as following in the view:

```
item_change_form_list = zip (list1, list2, list3)
```

Is it possible to pass a `zip` object in the `include` tag? Thanks.

Comment: django template has a `make_list` filter to create a list form some objects. maybe it could help

Comment: @MahdiFirouzjah Thanks. I found some other problem in the code. The parsing of the ```zip``` object actually works. Closing this.