# Python list value show in html table

Tags: python, html, django

Following show my python return:

```
 return render(request,'school\Views\Spredictions.html'{'len':length,'final':Ol_result,'data':marks_sheet})
```

Here, final : - ['pass','pass',''fail,'fail'] like this

following show the my html code

```
                         <tbody>

                            {%for m in data%}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{m.student_name}}</td>

                                        <td>{{final}}</td>

                                      </tr>
                                  {%endfor%}

                                </tbody>
```

I want to show one by one value in table interface, but show like that

[output of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTfLF.png)

How to solve this problem. Any one can help me
Thank you

Comment: I think you have to make a second for-each lopp for the predict result

Comment: @Elikill58 I try this but how to add that for loop in same time. Beacuse there is "for-loop" for student name

Comment: you can use nested for loop, A for loop inside another for loop

Comment: Yeoh, but that situation, student name repeat according to the predict result size @Rasheedkotoor

Comment: `<td>{{final.forloop.counter0}}</td>` it doesn't work? 

Comment: I think you are trying to loop two lists _together_ in Django, is that what you want? See [Iterating through two lists in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415865/iterating-through-two-lists-in-django-templates)

Comment: @RezaHeydari I also tried this. But no result show

Answer (score 0):

I created a list using zip()

```
mylist1 = zip(student_name1,Ol_result)
```

```
return render(request,'school\Views\Spredictions.html',{'mylist':mylist1,'final':Ol_result,'data':marks_sheet})
```

Html code

```
  <tbody>
        {%for item1, item2 in mylist%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{item1}}</td>
                 <td>{{item2}}</td>

              </tr>
           {%endfor%}
</tbody>
```

Problem solved